# Trig Function with integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $$\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=\frac{e^{\sin x}}{x},\quad\,x>0$$
if $$\int_1^4\frac{2e^{\sin x^2}}{x}\ dx=F(k)-(1)$$

then one of the possible value of $k$ is?

I guess we could some $u$ substitution for the equation on row $2$, but I'm not entirely sure how, and would appreciate some insights. The answer is $16$.

Comment: Is it $\sin(x^2)$ or $\sin^2(x)$ ?

Comment: @ JiaoCtagon. I did answer your question?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon. I see you’ve set a bounty and are looking for a “reputable source”. Tbh, I don’t see how an answer from a reputable source will change anything for a question like this. If you don’t understand my hints, take a look at the spoiler. If you still don’t understand with the spoilers, you can ask in the comments.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Let $x=\sqrt t$ and then use the definition of a definite integral.

Edit: I don't really know why I have a down vote, but my hints do the job.

> After $x=\sqrt t$,
>  $$\int_1^{16}\frac{e^{\sin t}}{t}\ dt$$
>  now just look at the upper bound.

Comment: nice hidden answer... I didn't know you could do that... it was the $>!$ characters?

Comment: @Joako. It's pretty neat. I didn't know about it too until I saw someone else use it recently.